# Can Google Maps find every street in a city by the number?

Tags: google-maps

I was searching around my neighbourhood and realized that, after punching in a few numbers in the area, Google Maps will auto-suggest close-by areas and other places relative to that number.

For example: I search "21 Boogie Lane, Boogie City." I clear the prompt and I see "21 Spooky Lane, Boogie City." I continue searching and sometimes I've gotten up to 4 suggestions.

Does this one can search all areas of a city by just address number/house number/etc. (e.g., "21 Bob Street" or "23 Bob Street"); or one could get Maps to show every numerical marking on every street?

For example, I want every "21" listed:

"21 Bob Street"

"21 Chapstick Street"

"21 Hunky Drive"

Etc. Does Google Maps have an option to show this natively or is additional software needed?